# How to use two LIKE in where clause in single SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from SMS_Send s 
where (s.ReceiverNo  like '071' or s.SchduledD like '078') 
and SchduledD between '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'
order by SchduledD
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: What is the data type of ReceiverNo ?

Comment: It is very unusual to see LIKE without any wilcard. Maybe you mean like '%071%'?

Comment: SchduledD is the date data type or else?

Comment: `SchduledD like '078'` and `SchduledD between '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'` clash.

Comment: Please add some sample data to this question.

Comment: Please read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically the part : *After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from SMS_Send s 
where s.ReceiverNo  like '071' or s.SchduledD like '078' 
and s.SchduledD >= '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and s.SchduledD <='2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'
order by SchduledD
```

Comment: A good answer usually has some explanation on what (in your opinion) the problem is and how this answer solves that problem.

Comment: Will never return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you picked wrong column name in case of where condition

```
select * from SMS_Send s 
where (s.ReceiverNo='071' or s.ReceiverNo ='078')  
and date_data_type_column  '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'-- wrong column name here date column need
order by SchduledD
```

For  `(s.ReceiverNo  like '071' or s.SchduledD like '078')` this condition you can use `in` like below

```
s.ReceiverNo in (071,078)
```

`SchduledD between '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'` for this condition you have to pick date data type in column of your table,i assume
ScheduledDate is date type column of your table then

```
ScheduledDate between '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-08-31 00:00:00.000'
```